# Airwatch Rest API for Reboot Device

Tags: airwatch, airwatchsdk

My question is regarding the Airwatch Rest API.
Is there any command(API) available for rebooting the device in Airwatch Rest API(Programmatically), like Lock, OsUpdate, etc.

Thanks,
MR

Answer (score 0):

There is no Airwatch API available to reboot device but this could be done by programming. You can use `EmdkWrapper Extension` for `Zebra`, `Honeywell` and `Motorola` devices and for `Samsung` you can use few other libraries.

```
public bool RebootDevice()
{
    return EmdkWrapper.current.SetProfile();
}
```